# OpenCV Calibrating Camera cropping error

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, crop, opencv3.0

I am working on calibrating my camera for OpenCV 3. Currently I am following tutorials and documentation and I have come across a problem. The end of my code has me crop the image, as to remove the visible distortion (as seen bellow)[image: Working Distorted Image]
However when I try this I sometimes get the error
`libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data`
It does not stop the program from running, however it saves an image with no pixels. I assume the crop function is cropping the entire image and this happens about 80%~ of the time.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import time

thyme = ('1')

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:6,0:9].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (6,9),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        ticks = time.time()
        thyme = str(ticks)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (6,9), corners2,ret)

        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

        img = cv2.imread('left1.jpg')
        h,  w = img.shape[:2]
        newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))

        # undistort
        dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

        # crop the image
        x,y,w,h = roi
        print('1')
        dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        print('2')
        cv2.imwrite('calibresult' + thyme + '.png',dst)
        print('3')

        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The print statements are included so that I can see if the image throws the error or if it comes out clean.

EDIT: Here is my error

`1
2
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
3
1
2
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
3
1
2
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
3`

Comment: Use `np.uint8` as your array data type : `dst = np.array(dst,dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: This doesn't change anything, I placed it above and below `dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]` and it does the exact same thing @Kasramvd

Comment: What is assigned to roi variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this problem is to add `dist = np.array([-0.13615181, 0.53005398, 0, 0, 0]) # no translation` below the line `ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)`